# How can I change Xtype property by device Android & iOS?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, extjs, sencha-touch

I am using **Extjs6.0.2** to create project , but now I have problem when I create xtype : 'namefield' cause this type of xtype support on Android and not support iOS device ,However I hope that I will find solution , How  can I can xtype by using by this.

`lookupReference('txtPhoneNo').setConfig('xtype','numbercode')` this code replace in `main.js`  ,

```
{

            xtype:'fieldset',
            items:[{

                minLength: 9,
                maxLength: 10, 
                xtype: 'textcode',
                cls: 'acledaTxt',
                itemId: 'txtPhoneNo',
                id: 'phonNo' ,
                reference: 'txtPhoneNo',

            }]

        },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change a component xtype runtime.

Instead you can, create the two components and hide or show the correct one using

```
if (Ext.os.is.iOS) {
    // iPad, iPod, iPhone, etc.
}
```

or you can create your component dinamically like this:

```
var xtype='';
if (Ext.os.is.iOS) {
    xtype='IOSXTYPE'
}else if(Ext.os.is.Android){
    xtype='AndroidXTYPE'
}
var component= Ext.create({
    xtype:xtype
});
```

Comment: How about android device

Comment: Have a look to sencha docs, here is Ext.os.is method http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/modern/Ext.os.html#method-is

Comment: best thank for answer but I still have problem with Android I want to use Numeric key and Input Number but I can't do, cause Keyboard in android Device still display Text Keyboard , can be input Text into Text field , cloud u  have any solution for Help , I really want to Display Keyboard Number  in Android Device , one more thing If I use  xtype:'numberfield' How can I put 0 in first number  (Ex: 010423384) ? What should I put 0 number on first number

Comment: var me    = this,
           input = me.getComponent().element.down('input');

        input.set({
            pattern : '[0-9]*'
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);

Comment: I try to apply code  var me    = this,
           input = me.getComponent().element.down('input');

        input.set({
            pattern : '[0-9]*'
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);  In Android device but still have problem keyborad still have text but My issue is Numeric only ,

Comment: Best thank for support And Help now I can Find salution ,